# Docker-compose: how to prevent all implicit profiles enabled for a service

Tags: docker-compose, profile

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  mysql:

  webServer1:
    profiles: ['server1']

  webServer2:
    profiles: ['server2']

  client:
    profiles: ['server1', 'server2']
```

Up: no problems:

```
 docker-compose --profile server1 up
```

For some reason, the client not started. start client:

```
 docker-compose --profile server1 start client
```

Error:

```
 no such service webServer2
```

All the profiles for the client are enabled. This is not intended
since --profile has been specified. Same error for viewing log for the client service:

```
 docker-compose --profile server1 logs client
```

Is there a way not to add additional profiles?

### UPDATE

Need to re-create one service container and keep all other existing containers(with data) in the profile. e.g.,

```
docker-compose --profile server1 create client
```